# Can I skip nodes in ASP.NET Menu Control?

Tags: asp.net, web.sitemap

I have a web.sitemap like this:

```
<siteMapNode url="~/Default.aspx" title="Home" description="" >
    <siteMapNode title="Node 1" description="">
        <siteMapNode url="" title="Node 1-1" description="" />
        <siteMapNode url="" title="Node 1-2" description="" />
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode title="Node 2" description="">
        <siteMapNode url="" title="Node 2-1" description="" />
        <siteMapNode url="" title="Node 2-2" description="" />
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMapNode>
```

If I use an ASP.NET menu control (with StaticDisplayLevels=2), I get this:

> | Home | Node 1 | Node 2 |

Is there a property for skipping "Home" and get this menu (from that sitemap):

> | Node 1 | Node 2 |

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using a SiteMapsDataSource you can skip the root node by setting the ShowStartingNode property to false.

Comment: Great, thanks. The property is in the DataSource, not the menu control where I was looking

Comment: I also had to switch StaticDisplayLevels from 2 to 1, since the starting node is not showing now

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't already using a `SiteMapDataSource` to populate the `Menu`, you can do that and set its `ShowStartingNode` property to `false` (and, as noted in the comment above, decrement the `StaticDisplayLevels` by 1, since you're removing a level) like this:

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="MenuSource" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />
```

Of course, this only works for the root node. To skip other nodes or entire levels of nodes, it would be necessary to massage the source Xml before populating the `Menu` (for example, use some xslt to strip out a class of nodes).